# Get second word of String not recognized

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
String myString = "Hello world";

firstWord = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf(" "));
secondWord= myString.substring(1, myString.indexOf(" "));
```

The first word is being recognized but the second one is actually cutting a character. So:

`first: Hello`

`Second: ello`

How can I get the second word?

Thank you

Comment: You need to use the overload of `indexOf` with two arguments.  Look it up in the javadocs.  Hint: the `indexOf(String)` method doesn't remember where you got to last time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that there are exactly 2 words, then you can just do this:

```
String myString = "Hello World";
int indexOfFirstSpace = myString.indexOf(" ");
String firstWord = myString.substring(0, indexOfFirstSpace);
String secondWord = myString.substring(indexOfFirstSpace + 1);
```

The second word is the just the substring from the index after the index of the space, all the way to the end of the string.

If you are not sure how many words there are, you might as well use `split` to split the string:

```
String[] words = myString.split(" ");
if (words.length >= 2) {
    String firstWord = words[0];
    String seconfWord = words[1];
}
```

Comment: The second one is a better implementation of what I'm trying to do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
    String myString = "Hello world";
    index(" ") will always give you the index of first occurrence of " ". So in
    String firstWord = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf(" "));
    you start with character at 0th index and end index will be first occurrence " " which is not included.
    Hello

    Now in your second 
    String secondWord= myString.substring(1, myString.last indexOf(" "));
    you are going to start with second character.
    ello

    **If you want to get words based in space as a separator the right way is to use split**

    **Example**
    String[] words = myString.split("\\s+");
    firstWord = words[0];
    secondWord = words[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

`secondWord= myString.substring(1, myString.indexOf(" "));`

**Why your code didn't work:**
For the above line of code, you are starting at "1" index of the string. Index one starts at "e" because you start counting from 0. So, When you start at "e" and stop at the next space, " ", that wouldn't' work, because it will just throw the words between "e" and " ". Which ends up being ello *(note. it doesn't include space)*

**To fix this run:** `secondWord= myString.substring(myString.indexOf(" "), 11);` or `secondWord= myString.substring(6, 11);`

***Note the ending index, for example, 11 in our case from the `myString.substring(6, 11)`, is one plus(+) the current computer index. In this case, the letter "d" was indexed 10 but you always add one to the ending index.***